# I want filter emails using javascript array

Tags: javascript, html

I have filtered the array based on emails but i want the emails to appear one after the other and also other which doesnt have gmail, hotmail, yahoo as domain must store in other section in the table, how to solve this problem please help me with a solution. 
My code is as follows:

```js
let  emails = [
    "albert.eisntein@gmail.com", "leonardo_da_vinci@hotmail.com", "jagadish_chandra_bose@yahoo.com", "alan_turing@yahoo.com", "srinivasa.ramanujan@gmail.com", "bjarne_stroustrup@yahoo.com", "max.planck@gmail.com", "nikola.tesla@hotmail.com", "galileo_galilei@hotmail.com", "a.p.j.abdul.kalam@gmail.com", "richard.stallman@inbox.com", "john_von_neumann@mail.com", "c_v_raman@yahoo.com", "isaac.newton@yandex.com", "s_chandrashekar@hotmail.com", "james_gosling@shortmail.com", "ken.thompson@gmail.com", "stephen_hawking@rediffmail.com", "marie_curie@yahoo.com", "michael.faraday@hotmail.com", "charles.babbage@hotmail.com" 
  ],
  filteredEmails = {};;


emails.forEach((el) => {
  let domain = el.split('@')[1];
  if (filteredEmails.hasOwnProperty(domain)) {
     filteredEmails[domain].push(el);
  } else {
    filteredEmails[domain] = [el];
  }
});
document.write("<tr><td>"+ filteredEmails['gmail.com']+ "</td>");
document.write("<td>"+ filteredEmails['hotmail.com'] + "</td>");
document.write("<td>"+ filteredEmails['yahoo.com'] + "</td>");
document.write("<td>"+ filteredEmails['others']+ "</td></tr>");
```

```html
<h1>Table of Emails</h1>
<table border="1">
<th>Gmail</th>
<th>Hotmail</th>
<th>Yahoo</th>
<th>Others</th>
</table>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```js
let  emails = [
    "albert.eisntein@gmail.com", "leonardo_da_vinci@hotmail.com", "jagadish_chandra_bose@yahoo.com", "alan_turing@yahoo.com", "srinivasa.ramanujan@gmail.com", "bjarne_stroustrup@yahoo.com", "max.planck@gmail.com", "nikola.tesla@hotmail.com", "galileo_galilei@hotmail.com", "a.p.j.abdul.kalam@gmail.com", "richard.stallman@inbox.com", "john_von_neumann@mail.com", "c_v_raman@yahoo.com", "isaac.newton@yandex.com", "s_chandrashekar@hotmail.com", "james_gosling@shortmail.com", "ken.thompson@gmail.com", "stephen_hawking@rediffmail.com", "marie_curie@yahoo.com", "michael.faraday@hotmail.com", "charles.babbage@hotmail.com" 
  ],
  filteredEmails = {};;


emails.forEach((el) => {
  let domain = el.split('@')[1];
  if (filteredEmails.hasOwnProperty(domain)) {
     
     if( domain.match( /gmail\.com|hotmail\.com|yahoo\.com/ ) ) {
      filteredEmails[domain].push(el);
    } else {
    filteredEmails['others'].push(el);
    }
     
  } else {
    if( domain.match( /gmail\.com|hotmail\.com|yahoo\.com/ ) ) {
      filteredEmails[domain] = [el];
    } else {
    filteredEmails['others'] = [el];
    }
  }
});

document.write("<tr><td>"+ filteredEmails['gmail.com']+ "</td>");
document.write("<td>"+ filteredEmails['hotmail.com'] + "</td>");
document.write("<td>"+ filteredEmails['yahoo.com'] + "</td>");
document.write("<td>"+ filteredEmails['others']+ "</td></tr>");
```

```html
<h1>Table of Emails</h1>
<table border="1">
<th>Gmail</th>
<th>Hotmail</th>
<th>Yahoo</th>
<th>Others</th>
</table>
```